# tsql to know when a database was last shrunk

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

In SQL 2000, 2005 and 2008, how can  I know when databases were last shrunk on a MS SQL server?

I want to do this using TSQL.

Regards

Manjot

Comment: If there's still time to talk you out of shrinking your db, consider this: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files.aspx

Comment: I am against shrinking, so this is to find if someone has done it.

Comment: Ah, interesting...I'm curious to see what people come up with

Comment: I have scripts for 2005 and above but not for sql 2000. So I am interested in something that can be applied to all environments. See http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/05/13/when-was-the-last-time-a-database-or-file-was-shrunk.aspx

Comment: surely the only people with sufficient access to shrink a DB are admins? That narrows it down a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for shrinking of database one uses `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` or `DBCC SHRINKFILE`, you can try to solve your problem with server audits from the group `DBCC_GROUP` (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280663.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx)

Comment: can i use it on sql 2000?